# put string in array, split by every second line

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to convert my string into array, Im giving you examples of what i want and what Ive tried. My string looks like this:

```
Height:
3/16
Color:
Standard Red
Material:
Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
Package Quantity:
1000/Pkg
Reusable:
Yes
Size:
3/16 H x 1/4 W
```

I want it to convert it in array to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Height: 3/16
    [1] => Color: Standard Red
    [2] => Material: Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
    [3] => Package Quantity: 1000/Pkg
    [4] => Reusable: Yes
    [5] => Size: 3/16 H x 1/4 W
)
```

I tried with this:

```
$array = explode("\n", $string);
```

But Ive got this for the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Height:
    [1] => 3/16
    [2] => Color:
    [3] => Standard Red
    [4] => Material:
    [5] => Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
    [6] => Package Quantity:
    [7] => 1000/Pkg
    [8] => Reusable:
    [9] => Yes
    [10] => Size:
    [11] => 3/16 H x 1/4 W
    [12] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track by separating the string into lines. You then need to [group the array into pairs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) of lines, and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them together. Here I'm using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to modify each of the pairs at once, but you could also do this for a simple for-loop if it's clearer.

```
$lines = explode("\n", trim($string));

$combined = array_map(
  function($line) { return implode(' ', $line); },
  array_chunk($lines, 2)
);
```

`$combined` should now match the output in your question. See https://3v4l.org/ZdgWS for a full example.

Comment: Great this is what i want. Thanks.

This is my result, how to remove last element if is empty?

    [0] => Height:
 3/16
    [1] => Color:
 Standard Red
    [2] => Material:
 Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
    [3] => Package Quantity:
 1000/Pkg
    [4] => Reusable:
 Yes
    [5] => Size:
 3/16 H x 1/4 W
    [6] =>

Comment: The easiest way would be to just trim the string before exploding - I've updated the first line in my answer

Comment: I want to remove these number keys(0,1,2) And replace them with string before two dots in array elements values. So the final result will be:

    [Height] => 3/16 

How i can do that

Comment: @doki look at my answer please I think it will be good solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<key>.+):\n(?<value>.+)/', $s, $a);
$result = array_combine($a['key'], $a['value']);

print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Height] => 3/16
    [Color] => Standard Red
    [Material] => Die-cut, pressure-sensitive paper
    [Package Quantity] => 1000/Pkg
    [Reusable] => Yes
    [Size] => 3/16 H x 1/4 W
)
```

So, you need only these 2 functions to use:
[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)